# Microsoft sources no connection

Tags: networking, microsoft-office, connection, onedrive, microsoft-teams

All Microsoft sources are not working for 1 week at least in one of my computers:

[Here you can see my Microsoft news not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o01Av.png)

[Here you can see Teams not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw7KG.png)

[OneDrive won't connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXCE.png)

In my laptop everything is working but in my main computer not.

Not sure what else I can check but I don't know how to fix this...

Reinstalled Teams but obviously didn't make any effect I just don't know what to try

**EDIT:** Microsoft Outlook is working fine

Comment: Reset the network on your desktop computer  ....   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
(b) Update / reinstall the network driver.   Test after these steps.

Comment: Hello @John thanks for your help but didn't work

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10    Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.

Comment: @John I ran the Windows 10 Installer and after repair & update it still doesn't works

Comment: The content in the screenshot is not in English, which seems to show that there is a problem with the network?

Comment: yes sorry it's a network issue or seems like

Comment: You said other computers were working fine, so network may not be the reason unless incompatible with your Windows 10 desktop (not really likely).

Comment: it was working in that desktop 1 week ago

Answer (score 0):

> All Microsoft sources are not working for 1 week at least in one of my
> computers:

The simple repair (DISM / SFC) did not work.

The Windows Repair Install did not work.

At this point then, you need to back up all your data and documents, make sure of your backup, and then install Windows fresh.

Once running again, restore your files.